# Jenkins giving The SDK Directory doesn't exist

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to setup continuous integration with `Jenkins` on an `android` `gradle` project

When I build it, I get the following error:

```
[Android Gradle Jenkins Experiment2] $ "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Android Gradle Jenkins Experiment2/gradlew" build
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
The SDK directory '/Users/chaz/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist.
```

The following is part of my jenkins configuration:

```
ANDROID_HOME
/Users/chaz/Library/Android/sdk

JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

My machine is `OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6`

I have tried the following:

1. Thinking it is a permission issue, gave chmod -R 777 for the sdk directory
2. Double checked the `sdk.dir` in `local.properties` file (It is pointing to `/Users/chaz/Library/Android/sdk`).
3. Removed added back `ANDROID_HOME` env variable from within jenkins configuration (didn't help).

When I googled, I found someone faced the same [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/Y2lYvFrpqa0). And the solution provided was as follows:

Solution

> That's most likely happening because you're overriding ANDROID_HOME — 
>   remove environment customisations like that and then the SDK should 
>   install fine.

Acknowledgement

> Thanks and yeah, it was overlapping of env variables. I have removed all except the global one and kept it in ${ANDROID_HOME}.

How should I do the ***all except the global one and kept it in ${ANDROID_HOME}.*** part of the solution?

**Edit:** I was successfully able to use Jenkins on a windows machine with same jenkins configuration (I was able to build successfully, install apk in a device too).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Smells like a permission problem ..

Comment: I'm not very sure, as I mentioned I have already tried chmod -R 777 for the sdk directory

Comment: yea but if jenkins cannot see the parent directories ..

Comment: Hmm I'll adding chmod at parent directory

Comment: Yes! **Fixed! Permission was indeed the issue.** 1st I executed chmod 777 at /Users/chaz/Library/Android/ and it didn't work. Then I ran chmod -R 777 at /Users/chaz/Library/ and it **worked**! Can you move your comment to an answer? I shall mark it as answered and upvote. Thanks :)

Comment: Great! Added an answer.

Comment: I am having the same issue when running Jenkins on Docker, but it works fine with generic war package. It seems like Docker is not able to see the directory on the host.

Comment: i have same problem, but i have tried to `chmod -R 777` and not working, still `The SDK directory '/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist`. How to solve it ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This smells like a permission problem. You might have given permission to the sdk-dir but not the parent directory.

Comment: @ligi Having the same problem Even after giving the permission. Can you please help me?

Comment: I am using the Ubuntu system. I have set ANDROID_HOME as custom android sdk path which is located in document directory. When jenkins run the job show the sdk directory does not exist.

Comment: I also by enabling the Environment Variable. No luck.

Comment: This is the location of my android sdk /home/bhavdip/Documents/AndroidSdk

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 12 bhavdip bhavdip  4096 Feb 21 15:51 AndroidSdk

Comment: As I mentioned before, I had to do **chmod -R 777 at /Users/chaz/Library/**  I had executed **chmod 777 at /Users/chaz/Library/Android/** and it didn't work. So in your case, make sure the program has access to al parent directories. So, **/home/bhavdip/Documents** for example.

Answer (score 3):

In my situation, it happened because file

```
local.properties
```

had been added to .gitignore

(I assemble from remote)

Comment: For me, there was an extra space after `Android/` as 
 shown here `sdk.dir=/Users/amar/Library/Android/ `.  Removing space solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

I just want to say how we fixed this problem in our project. It may help someone.

The working directory of our Jenkins is under "/User/shared", and our SDK is under "/User/foo"

We tried to give user foo and everyone permission to the SDK folder and its parent folders, but it did not work.

Then we installed SDK under /user/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Android/SDK via Android SDK Manager, and gave user foo and everyone permission to the new SDK folder and its parent folders. Also, we changed the SDK Path to new in Jenkins project configuration. Then it works.

Answer (score 1):

As said by @ligi it's due to permission problem. So it can be fixed by 2 ways

1. Run below commands in ~/Library/ path by using terminal

   ```
   chmod 777
   ```

   at `/Users/username/Library/`. Check permission by execute `ls -s` command

   So `/Users/username/Library/` should now show the permission like this:

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x@
   ```
2. Second way, run below command on Terminal to unhide library inside File explorer

   ```
   chflags nohidden ~/Library/
   ```

   So now navigate & right click on Library folder -> Get info -> Scroll 
   down -> change permission on permission in dialog

   [Setting permission for Library directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mppKN.png)

Now run jerkin, it should be able to access the sdk directory inside Library

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, found next solution: remove ANDROID_HOME in Jenkins environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System

Check "Environment variables"

add name: ANDROID_HOME, value -> the full path to your android sdk e.g /Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk

click apply then save and retry build