# jenkins can not find android SDK

Tags: jenkins

I try to build a HelloWorld Android project with jenkins, but fail.

**Error message:**

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/home/xxxx/Android/Sdk' does not exist.
```

But I am sure that SDK directory exists, because I can success build it in command line.

What I have try:

1. set ANDROID_HOME in jenkins and remove project local.properties

   - build in jenkins fail, can not find sdk
   - build in command fail, can not find sdk
2. add project local.properties

   - build in jenkins fail, can not find sdk
   - build in command success

**Fixed**
[see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568402/jenkins-giving-the-sdk-directory-doesnt-exist)

**Reason**

jenkins has no pemission to access of user(xxxx) home folder.

Then I run `chmod 777 /home/xxxx` and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this.

[see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568402/jenkins-giving-the-sdk-directory-doesnt-exist)

**Reason**

jenkins has no pemission to access of user(xxxx) home folder.

Then I run `chmod 777 /home/xxxx` and it works now.