# Jenkins Android build failed

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration

Tried building Android app with Jenkins and the build failed with following log. Any help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It's showing sdk path not found. Please check their if it exist their or not.

Comment: It's late but I think this will work for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568402/jenkins-giving-the-sdk-directory-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong the sdk directory path '/Users/NiraiSri/Library/Android/sdk'.

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties

Add ANDROID_HOME to your sdk path and rebuild.

[image]