# The SDK directory '/var/jenkins_home/Android/Sdk' does not exist

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins docker running on an ubunto machine.
I want to create a CI\CD environment for my app.

I installed android-SDK using apt-get install command.

When I run the build command by invoke grade I get this error:
"The SDK directory '/var/jenkins_home/Android/Sdk' does not exist"

I installed Jenkins using docker
I installed android-SDK

I want to be able to create an appropriate build for my app

Comment: Are you installed the android-SDK in the host or in the jenkins docker container?

Comment: I hope this will work for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568402/jenkins-giving-the-sdk-directory-doesnt-exist

Comment: @JRichardsz
Sorry for the late response.

Yes. I'm using  a Jenkins docker container.
I installed android-SDK in the host.